# How to display the logged in user details in a table format using session in node js , react js , sql?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, reactjs, express

[This the view page where user details are redirected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgjeH.png)

Hello all currently i am working on a project which has two form login and user details form.
When users login and fills the details form after that it will redirect it to view page where he/she can view, edit ,delete his/her record. But when user login only his records should be seen. In my case it is fetching all the records in a view page. I am using session in node js. I don't know what's gone wrong.

Server code

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cookie=require("cookie-parser");
const session=require("express-session");
const bodyparser=require("body-parser");
app.use(cors({
    origin:("http://localhost:3000"),
    methods:("GET","POST"),
    credentials:true
}));
app.use(cookie("secret"));
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(session({
    key:"userid",
    resave:false,
    saveUninitialized:false,
    secret:"userinfo",
    cookie:{
        expires:60*60*24,
    },
}))

app.use(express.json());
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'demo'
});
db.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    else {
        console.log("Mysql Connected");
    }
})

//var sess
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const cpassword = req.body.cpassword;
    db.query("SELECT  FROM registration WHERE email='"+email+"';", [email], (err, result) => {
        if(result){
            res.send({message:"User already exists"})
        }
        else{
            db.query("INSERT INTO registration (email,password,cpassword) VALUES(?,?,?)", [email, password, cpassword], (err, result) => {
               if(err){
                   res.send(err);
               }
               else{
                   res.send({message:"Registered Successful"})
               }
            })
        }
    })

    
})

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    db.query("SELECT * FROM registration WHERE  email='"+email+"' AND password='"+password+"';", [email,password], (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            res.send({err:err});

        }
        if(result.length>0){
              req.session.user=result;
              console.log( req.session.user)
              res.send(result);
            // sess=req.session;
            // sess.userid=req.body.email;
            //  console.log(req.session)
             
        else{
            res.send({message:"Wrong username/passsword"})
        }
    })
     app.get("/login",(req,res)=>{
         if(req.session.user){
             res.send({loggedIn:true,user:req.session.user})
            
         }
         else{
             res.send({loggedIn:false});
     
     }
 })
 app.post('/add', (req, res) => {
        const firstname=req.body.firstname;
        const lastname=req.body.lastname;
        const email=req.body.email;
        const mobile=req.body.mobile;
        const address=req.body.address;
        const city=req.body.city;
        const pincode=req.body.pincode;
        const conference=req.body.conference;
        const seminar=req.body.seminar;
        const paper=req.body.paper;
        //const user_id=req.body.user_id;
       
        if(firstname==""||lastname==""||email==""||mobile==""||address==""||city==""||pincode==""||conference==""||seminar==""||paper=="")
        {
            return res.status(422).json({error:"Please Fill the form correctly"});
    
        }
        
           
        db.query("INSERT INTO teacher  (firstname,lastname,email,mobile,address,city,pincode,conference,seminar,paper) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", [firstname,lastname,email,mobile,address,city,pincode,conference,seminar,paper], (err, result) => {
             console.log(err)   
            
        //    if(result){
        //     //sess=req.session;
        //     req.session.user=result;
        //     console.log(req.session.user)
        //     res.send(result)
            //sess.email=req.body.email;
            //if(sess.email){
            //console.log( sess)
            //res.send(result)
            //res.redirect("/view");
           
            //}
           
          // }   
        //   else{
        //       res.send(err)
        //  }
           
        })
            
        
    })
    

        
            
//  })
//   
 app.get("/teachersdata" , (req, res) => {
     
     db.query("SELECT * FROM teacher ",(err,result)=>{
          if(result){
        
          res.send(result);
        
           }
            
    
        
        
     
    
        
 })
 app.get("/teachersdata/:id", (req, res) => {

      db.query('SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE id=?',[req.params.id], (err, result)=>{
          if(err){
              console.log('Error while fetching employee by id', err);
             
          }else{
              res.send(result)
          }
      })
    
        
 })
    app.get("/logout",(req,res)=>{
        console.log("logout page");
        //req.logout()
        console.log( req.session.user)
        res.clearCookie("user")
        //res.redirect("/login")
        req.session.destroy((err) => {
            res.redirect('/login') // will always fire after session is destroyed
          })

    })

})
app.put('/edit/:id',(req,res)=>{
    const firstname=req.body.firstname;
    const lastname=req.body.lastname;
    const email=req.body.email;
    const mobile=req.body.mobile;
    const address=req.body.address;
    const city=req.body.city;
    const pincode=req.body.pincode;
    const conference=req.body.conference;
    const seminar=req.body.seminar;
    const paper=req.body.paper;
    const id=req.params.id;
    db.query("UPDATE teacher SET firstname=?,lastname=?,mobile=?,email=?,address=?,city=?,pincode=?,conference=?,seminar=?,paper=? WHERE id=?",[id,firstname,lastname,email,mobile,address,city,pincode,conference,seminar,paper],(err,res)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        else{
            res.send(res);
        }
    })
})
app.delete("/delete/:id",(req,res)=>{
    db.query("DELETE FROM teacher WHERE id=?",[req.params.id],(result,err)=>{
        if(err){
            res.send(err)
        }
        else{
            res.send(result)
        }
    })
})
app.listen(3001)
```

This is the react code

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export const View = () => {
   const [teacherList, setteacherList] = useState([]);
   
  useEffect(() => {
    loadUsers();
  }, [])
  const loadUsers= async()=>{
    const result =await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/teachersdata");
    console.log(result)
    setteacherList(result.data)
  }
 
  


const deleteUser = async id => {
  await axios.delete(`/delete/${id}`);
  loadUsers();
};

 
  return (
    <div>
       
      <table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">FirstName</th>
      <th scope="col">LastName</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {
      teacherList.map((user,index)=>(
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">{index+1}</th>
          <td>{user.firstname}</td>
          <td>{user.lastname}</td>
          <td>{user.email}</td>
          <td>
           
            <Link class="btn btn-primary me-md-2" to={`/teachersdata/${user.id}`}>View</Link>
            <Link class="btn btn-outline-primary me-md-2" to={`/edit/${user.id}`}>Edit</Link>
            <Link class="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => deleteUser(user.id)}>Delete</Link>
            
          </td>
          </tr>
         
      ))}
    
  </tbody>
</table>
    </div>

  )

}
```

login page (client)

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = () => {
    axios.defaults.withCredentials=true;
    const history=useHistory();
    const [emailreg,setemail]=useState('');
    const [passreg,setpass]=useState('');
    
    const login=()=>{
        
        axios.post("/login",{
            email:emailreg,
            password:passreg,

        }).then((res)=>{
            //alert(res.data.message)
            //setLoginUser(res.data.user)
            //history.push("/add")
              //console.log(res);
             if(res.data.message){
                  alert(res.data.message);
              }
              else{
                 alert("Login Sucessfully");
                  history.push("/add")
          }
            
        })
        
        
    }
    

    return (
    
            <div className="login">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <label>Email ID</label>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>{
                setemail(e.target.value);
            }}/><br/>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" onChange={(e)=>{
                setpass(e.target.value);
            }}/><br/>
            <button onClick={login}>Login</button>
            
            
        </div>
        
        
    )
}

export default Login
```

User details page

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
const Main = () => {
  const [formStep, setFormStep] = useState(0);
  const history=useHistory();

   
    const [firstname,setfirstname]=useState('');
    const [lastname,setlastname]=useState('');
    const [email,setemail]=useState('');
    const [mobile,setmobile]=useState('');
    const [address,setaddress]=useState('');
    const [city,setcity]=useState('');
    const [pincode,setpincode]=useState('');
    const [conference,setconference]=useState('');
    const [seminar,setseminar]=useState('');
    const [paper,setpaper]=useState('');
    const [loginstatus,setlogin]=useState('');
    //const [userid,setuserid]=useState('');

  const completeFormStep = () => {
    setFormStep(step => step + 1)
  }
  const backFormStep = () => {
    setFormStep(step => step - 1)
  }
  
  const handlesubmit = () => {
    axios.post("http://localhost:3001/add",{
            firstname:firstname,
            lastname:lastname,
            email:email,
            mobile:mobile,
            address:address,
            city:city,
            pincode:pincode,
            conference:conference,
            seminar:seminar,
            paper:paper,
            //userid:userid

           

        }).then((res)=>{
            console.log("success");
           
           
            
           
           
            
        })
        

        history.push("/view")

        
  };
  
    useEffect(() => {
      axios.get("/login").then((res)=>{
          console.log(res)
          if(res.data.loggedIn===true){
          setlogin(res.data.user[0].email)
          // if(res.data.loggedIn===true){
          // setlogin(res.data.userid)
         }
      })
  }, []);

  
  return (
    <div className="create">
      <form method="POST">
        {formStep === 0 && (
          <section>
             <h1>{"Welcome" + loginstatus}</h1> 
            <h2>Names</h2>

            <label>First Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              required
              onChange={(e)=>{
                setfirstname(e.target.value);
            }}
              

            />


            <br />

            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              required
              onChange={(e)=>{
                setlastname(e.target.value);
            }}

            />

            <br />
            <button type="button" onClick={completeFormStep}>Next</button>
          </section>)}

        <div className="step2">
          {formStep === 1 && (
            <section>
              <h2>Contact</h2>

              <label>Email ID</label>
              <input
                type="email"
                required
                onChange={(e)=>{
                  setemail(e.target.value);
              }}

              />
              <br />
              {/* <label>UserID</label>
              <input
                type="userid"
                required
                onChange={(e)=>{
                  setuserid(e.target.value);
              }}
              />
              <br/>  */}
              <label>Mobile No.</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                required
                onChange={(e)=>{
                  setmobile(e.target.value);
              }}

              />
              <br />
              <button type="button" onClick={backFormStep}>Back</button>
              <button type="button" onClick={completeFormStep}>Next</button>
            </section>)}
        </div>

        <div className="step3">
          {formStep === 2 && (
            <section>
              <h2>Address</h2>
              <label>Address</label>
              <textarea onChange={(e)=>{
                setaddress(e.target.value);
            }}>

              </textarea>
              <br />

              <label>City</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                required
                onChange={(e)=>{
                  setcity(e.target.value);
              }}
              />
              <br />
              <label>Pincode</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                required
                onChange={(e)=>{
                  setpincode(e.target.value);
              }}

              />
              <br />
              <button type="button" onClick={backFormStep}>Back</button>
              <button type="button" onClick={completeFormStep}>Next</button>

            </section>)}
        </div>
        <div className="step4">
          {formStep === 3 && (
            <section>
              <h2>Conferences attended,seminar and paper presented</h2>

              <label>Conferences name</label>
              <textarea placeholder="conferences names" onChange={(e)=>{
                setconference(e.target.value);
            }}></textarea>

              <br />
              <label>Seminar attended</label>
              <textarea placeholder="seminar names"onChange={(e)=>{
                setseminar(e.target.value);
            }}></textarea>

              <br />
              <label>Paper presented</label>
              <textarea placeholder="paper names" onChange={(e)=>{
                setpaper(e.target.value);
            }}></textarea>
              <br />
              <button type="button" onClick={backFormStep}>Back</button>
              <button type="submit" onClick={handlesubmit}>Submit</button>
             
            </section>)}
          <div>


          
          </div>
         

        </div>




      </form>










    </div>
  );
}

export default Main
```

I want that when user login and fills details form only his or logged in user details should be displayed each users should get their own details in the view page after login. I am new to node js and react.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your logic for login in client side?

Comment: @SanishJoseph I have edited my post check now

Comment: After logging in, you are just going to an `add` route which I assume points to `Main`  component and there is no logic to see if the user is logged in that component. In your login screen you are not doing anything with the response you are getting. I will add rest as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are sending `{loggedIn:true,user:req.session.user}` after login but your client app ignores it now. What you can do is to save this object you receive after login on Local Storage so even if they refresh the page we will have access to the object.

After saving the object on local storage, in your `Main` component, you need to check if an object exists in the local storage and the `loggedIn` value is true and `user` session object has not expired. If any of these conditions are not met, you have to clear the local storage and redirect the user to login page.

I am not sure whether you have the expiry of session in the `user` object but you must have a cookie with expiry for sure.

I hope it's clear.

Comment: Yup I will try Thank you so much